# Group and sum worked hours by days

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a software to manage worked hours. For each day could be different activities. 
I wish to extract the worked hours for each worker in the last 7 days.

**Sample rows**

```
+----+------------+-------+----------+----------+
| id |    date    | order | operator | duration |
+----+------------+-------+----------+----------+
| 37 | 2016-06-12 |    27 |        1 |      180 |
| 38 | 2016-06-12 |    28 |        3 |      390 |
| 39 | 2016-06-12 |    27 |        1 |      480 |
| 40 | 2016-06-04 |    21 |        2 |      120 |
| 41 | 2016-05-07 |    27 |        1 |       90 |
| 42 | 2016-06-07 |    27 |        1 |      150 |
+----+------------+-------+----------+----------+
```

**The Query**

```
SELECT SUM(`duration`) as `hours_per_day`
FROM `sheets`
WHERE `operator` = 1 AND `date` = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

**Expected result:**

```
+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Operator: Avareage Joe                                                                |
+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Day:                   | 01 jul | 02 jul | 03 jul | O4 jul | 05 jul | 06 jul | 07 jul |
| Hours:                 | 8      | 7      | 9      | 8      | 9      | 8      | 6      |
+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: This would require a large (and ugly) pivot query using regular SQL, or dynamic SQL, and there is the problem of an operator not having data for one or more of the last seven days.  For that, you could use a calendar table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/ABU64998)**

```
SELECT 
 CURDATE(),
 SUM(CASE WHEN CURDATE()                  = `date` THEN `duration` ELSE 0 END) as today    ,    
 SUM(CASE WHEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY = `date` THEN `duration` ELSE 0 END) as yesterday,
 SUM(CASE WHEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY = `date` THEN `duration` ELSE 0 END) as `today - 2`,
 SUM(CASE WHEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY = `date` THEN `duration` ELSE 0 END) as `today - 3`, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY = `date` THEN `duration` ELSE 0 END) as `today - 4`,
 SUM(CASE WHEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY = `date` THEN `duration` ELSE 0 END) as `today - 5`,
 SUM(CASE WHEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY = `date` THEN `duration` ELSE 0 END) as `today - 6`
FROM `work`
where operator = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's try it like this:

```
SELECT    operator, `date`, (SUM(duration) / 60) as hours_per_day
FROM      sheets
WHERE     `date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY  operator, date
ORDER BY  operator, date
```

Just look at the `WHERE` clause first. We exclude everything that is more than 7 days old.

Then we use `GROUP BY` to take all the remaining rows and group them by operator and date, so you basically get small sub-results that you can work with.

I retained your `SUM(duration)` operation, which now calculates sums for every one of these little sub-results. I just added the division, because obviously you're storing minutes, not hours.

Finally we use `ORDER BY` to make sure the result doesn't look like a big mess.

Your result should look something like this:

```
 operator | date         | hours_per_day
 ---------------------------------------
 1        | 2016-07-01   | 4
 1        | 2016-07-02   | 6
 1        | 2016-07-03   | 6
 2        | 2016-07-01   | 8
 2        | 2016-07-02   | 7
```

Comment: And just a quick little tip: If you avoid using reserved words as identifiers, your queries look a lot less \`prickly\`. ;)